# Java Concurrency: Threads notifications

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, notifications

I have a java concurrency problem, it goes like this: There is a Servlet (*serv1*) that stores objects (representing messages) into a database. There is also a Thread (*t1*) that looks (in the database) for unsent messages and delivers them. *t1* runs every 5 minutes so, for efficiency purposes, *serv1* notifies *t1* every time it stores a message.

The question is: How the notification process is going to behave on a highly concurred scenario where serv1 is receiving an extremely high amount of requests and thus *t1* is being notified so much that it’d simulate a "*while (true)*"?.

Another question: How does the notification process will behave if *serv1* wants to notify *t1* but *t1* is already awake/running?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might want to checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue @Wilmer.  I suspect that the notification itself is relatively cheap compared to the cost of consuming and processing your messages.  If you are spinning consuming then messages then removing the notifications is not going to help the process and you will have to block your `serv1` thread somehow or offload the jobs to run later.

In terms of notifications, if no one is waiting then the `notify()` is effectively a no-op.  This is why it is important to check to see if there is anything to process *before* waiting on the signal -- all in a synchronized block.  It is best practice to also *loop* around the wait and check again when we are notified.  See this [race condition](http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/).

In general, this is a *very* common practice that is used in virtually all [producer/consumer thread models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) that I have seen.  The alternative is not to handle the square wave traffic changes.  Either your consumer (t1) is waiting too long and the buffers fill up or it is spinning too much and is consumer too much CPU checking the database.

Another thing to consider is to not use the database but to put the objects into a `BlockingQueue` for `t1` to consume directly.  If you need to store them in the database then put the IDs of the objects in the queue for `t1` to consume.  The thread will still need to poll the database on startup but you will save the polls later in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you notifying t1 at all? Why doesn't T1 on it's 5 minute sweep query the database and process all of the pending messages? Then you don't need a notification at all, you simply use the database.

Comment: The notification enhances the overall performance, i.e., it’d be nice to “awake” _t1_ so it doesn’t have to wait till its “sleeping cycle” is over.

Comment: Don't bother yourself with performance. Make it work first. If, __then__, you have performance problems, test them, decide a performance goal to be reached by adding improvements and then implement them and re-test.

Comment: @Wilmer It seems useless to have `t1` run every 5 minutes if every request is processed live; there will be nothing to process at the 5 minute.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Object o = new Object(); o.notify()` correctly, it has to be done after obtaining that object's monitor (becoming its owner; AKA `synchronize` on it). Moreover, the awakened thread that waits upon that monitor will have to wait yet again for the notifying thread to release that monitor and try to obtain it. Only then it shall continue processing.

So, when *t1* will be awakened, it will actually fight all other *serv1* threads for becoming owner of the monitor. It might obtain the monitor, thus stalling all *serv1* threads (not good). It might loose constantly to *serv1*'s threads and not process the accumulating messages in the database (just as bad, I guess).

What you should do, is let the producers (*serv1* threads) work asynchronously with the consumer (*t1*). *t1* should continue to run every X minutes (or seconds) and process all the messages altogether.
Another option, if you want to keep the thread in low activity: configure several consumer threads (*t1*, *t2*, *t3*... etc.). You can use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory)` for this purpose.